# sql mail and ssrs

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Is it possible to attach a report from SSRS as PDF and send using sql mail? the server is MSSQL 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use email delivery built into SSRS? Underneath, this uses SQL Agent anyway.

All versions of SSRS support email delivery. [Configuring email delivery for SQL 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972234(SQL.80).aspx).

For PDF... when you set up the subscription you specify the render format. I can't test this bit, but I assume PDF is supported here because PDF is supported anyway.

BOL link: [How to create an e-mail subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa256356(SQL.80).aspx)

We've also tested URL Access to generate PDFs followed by using SSIS emailing as attachment to work around some corporate limitations.

Comment: Umm.....Duh......, needless to say I am new to SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to save the report to the file system (not sure if SSRS 2000 can do that) then pick it up with the SQL Mail job.

Failing that setup a .NET app to connect to the web method that SSRS exposes (this is based on SQL 2005, so hopefully it'll work in 2000) and create the PDF and have the .NET app save it.  Then have the next step of the job grab the file and email it out.

I take is SSRS 2000 doesn't support email report delivery?